# Connect to VMware ESXi 5.5 Virtual Machine using WinSCP

Tags: virtualization, esxi5.5

I've been tasked with setting up an attack lab for my office. We have an ESXi 5.5 Server up an running with several virtual machines, however I've hit a snag;

We can't have the lab networked at all due to the nature of our work, but still need to connect to the VMs using WinSCP. We've got a management machine connected, but we can't connect to the internal VMs, despite having a DHCP instance bridging NICs together.

Is there a way I can get this working?

Comment: when you say "We can't have the lab networked at all" are you saying that the lab cannot be connected to the wider workplace network, but that the VMs themselves can talk to each other, or do you mean each guest is completely isolated from all other systems? Either way, you will need something less network-centric (and probably more cumbersome) than winscp.

Comment: I've set up pfSense with a static IP addrees on one NIC & starter DHCP off that, but still no joys. Effectively, the lab is for Cyber security research, hence the need for iaolation.